# How can I make session variables accessible to sub application

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am building an api that will interface with the MongoDB database and have mounted it as a subapplication. I have defined a session variable in my server controller.
However, any time that the server files need to talk to the api files the session variables are never passed off.
Heres the app.js file

```
//app.js file
'use strict';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'development';
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(session);
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var helmet = require('helmet');


var app = express();
app.use(helmet());
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/striv4");
var db = mongoose.connection;

// mongo error
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));

app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: new MongoStore({
    mongooseConnection: db
  })
}));
app.use(flash());
// make user ID available in templates
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.currentUser = {
                            username:req.session.username,
                            id: req.session.userId
                          };
  next();
});
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser('secreter'));
app.use(logger('dev'));

var api = require('./app_api/routes/index');
var serverRoutes = require('./server/routes/index');

//static file middleware
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('views',__dirname +'/server/views');
app.set('view engine','pug');

app.use('/',serverRoutes);
app.use('/api',api);



//custom error handler
app.use(function(error, req, res, next) {
  res.status(error.status || 500);
  res.send('Error: '+error.message);
});
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port: '+port);
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got the whole program listed so there is more than one way for this to have gone wrong. Here are my suggestions to fix this:

1. Check the version of `express-session` you've installed. (Just run `npm ls` in the terminal and in your root Node app folder where you're `package.json` file is). If it's equal to or greater than v1.5.0, you don't need the cookie-parser for sessions anymore. Comment out the `app.use` line for the cookie parser and see if this works.
2. If you still need cookie parser for some other reason, you should use **the same secret for sessions and the cookie parser**. In your code, you've set two *different* values for secret.
3. I've seen that the other big failure for sessions occurs if the session store is not correctly connected to your Node app. Cross-check that the database is available and working. In my experience, Express sessions will **fail silently** if it can't get to the DB.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have a git repo here https://github.com/fradway1990/striv4 if you wanted to look. The codes a bit on the rough side though. I don't know if this is helpful, but the session variables are only unavailable when I make requests through the request module.

Comment: Frankie - I've taken a look around the source. Where exactly are you making these requests? i.e. which file?

Comment: I'm making them in [/server/controllers/goal.server.controller.js](https://github.com/fradway1990/striv4/blob/master/server/controllers/goals.server.controller.js) 
The session varibles were set in [/server/controllers/users.server.controller.js](https://github.com/fradway1990/striv4/blob/master/server/controllers/users.server.controller.js)